# Java MouseListener not working once added to another class

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, mouselistener

Basically I have two classes, an `Infantry` class which is used to create units in a game, and a `Map` class which is used to paint everything (i.e. units, building, etc.) to the screen. I have a `MouseListener` in my `Infantry` class that takes the coordinates of the mouse upon click, sets the x and y variables of an image to those then repaints the image on the screen. When I directly make an `Infantry` object in my JFrame class this works fine, but I can't see the `Map` class being painted before hand. When I make the object within the `Map` class itself (which is my main objective), the `MouseListener` doesn't work, as in it won't register a click or any of the methods (I tried a console printout to test this). Right now I'm a little lost on why this won't work and any help would be much appreciated.
Infantry class:

```
public class Infantry extends JLabel{

private Image img;
private int bx;
private int by;
private MouseListener move = new Move();

public Infantry(String file, int Bx, int By){
    img = new ImageIcon(file).getImage();
    bx = Bx;
    by = By;
    setOpaque(false);
    addMouseListener(move);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponents(g);

    g.drawImage(img, bx, by, null);

}

private class Move implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bx = e.getX();
        by = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please post an SSCCE showing the problem.

Comment: You should override `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` instead.

Comment: I have done them all but none work.

Comment: @Legend: what do you mean by "pass mouseListeners"?

Comment: @Legend: yes you should stop talking. We use MouseListeners on JLabels all the time, and they respond to mouse events just fine.

Comment: @ yanman, do as JB Nizet suggests and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: There's really not much else to it though. The `Map` class just creates an `Infantry` object then just has `(Infantry Object).paintComponent(g);` within the `Map paintComponent`. When adding to the frame directly, an object is made then just added to the container.

Comment: That's the problem. You should not call paintComponent() yourself. Swing should call it for you.

Comment: How does that fix my problem of a MouseListener not working?

Comment: Why are you overriding the paintComponent() method of a JLabel to paint an image? Just add an ImageIcon to the label and let the label do the painting. In any case you definitely would not invoke super.paintComponents(). Note the "s".

Comment: The "s" was a typo so thank you for noticing that. That's good point and I should have thought of that. I'll try that now. Thanks!

Comment: @camickr Thank you very much! I made the image the label's ImageIcon and moved the MouseListener to my `Map` class and now it gets registered!